# Which module features an undead pirate fleet waiting to attack a town?

Tags: d20-system, product-identification

I came across an online review/synopsis of this d20/Pathfinder module but for the life of me I can't remember its name now. Here is the premise:

- It's an urban adventure, set in a rather large port city or town.
- The backstory is that pirates (or some seafaring antagonists) sought to conquer the town, and a traitor was supposed to light the signal fire when the time to attack comes.
- The fire was never lit and somehow the pirates were trapped in the cove where they were waiting and somehow all died. They became undead, and the ship became haunted.
- However, if a certain ritual is performed, and the signal fire is lit on certain days, the undead fleet will emerge to attack.
- In present days, someone wants to make use of this and in the ensuing chaos, take over the town.

I have looked through the Pazio's Pathfinder and D20 lists of modules, but couldn't find it. It's not *From Shore to Sea* or *Treasure of Chimera's Cove*

**Updates**

- It's not one of the Freeport adventures either.

Comment: Is this a generic D20 adventure or a Pathfinder adventure? If it's a Pathfinder specific adventure this should be tagged with Pathfinder instead of D20.

Comment: I can't remember, but it's definitely a D&D 3.5 onward adventure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone on RPG Geeks nailed it for me. It's [The Silent Tide](http://paizo.com/products/btpy84k0).

Comment: Nice, I'll need to check that out.